# Filter dictionary on the basis of key value present in list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary D1 like this

[image]

and a list L1 like this

[image]

I want to have a dictionary like this (Filtering those key-value pairs whose key is present in the list )

[image]

So, I tried `D1.Where(x => L1.Contains(x.Key))` but i got a dictionary of 2 rows with empry string in `key` and `value`.

Please advise.

Comment: You wouldn't get a dictionary from calling `Where`. It would just be a sequence of key/value pairs. Please provide a [mcve] so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Also, how are you viewing the results? Linq results are hard to analyze in the debugger since they use iterators and not concrete structures.

Comment: @DStanley: I was checking the variable value after execution of the step.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's it all I had "D1.Where(x => L1.Contains(x.Key))"

Comment: Well that doesn't return a dictionary. It returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. Again, if you could provide a [mcve] we can help you far more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some thing like this :

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3}};

List<string> list = new List<string> {"A","B"};

var result = dictionary.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Key)).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = dictionary.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: You could do `ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)` so the result is another `Dictionary<string, int>` instead of a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`

Comment: Nice note.I'll add it

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you need

In case all keys of D1 are present in L1 without mutating D1

```
Dictionary<string, string> D2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
L1.ForEach(x => D2[x] = D1[x]);
```

OR

```
var D2 = L1.ToDictionary(el => el, key => D1[key]);
```

Safe option:

```
var D2 = D1.Keys.Intersect(L1).ToDictionary(key => key, key => D1[key]);
```

and even more, depends on your creativity

Note that this is slow for big list and dictionary

```
D1.Where(x => L1.Contains(x.Key))
```